# Soft keyboard pushes NavigationView's headerLayout up

Tags: android

When focusing a `EditText` and the soft keyboard gets opened, it pushes up my `headerLayout` in my `NavigationView` layout (see screenshots).
I'm assuming it has something to do with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in my `RelativeLayout` in `nav_header_navigation.xml`. If I remove it, the content is not pushed up, but it doesn't fit the screen correctly as it did before.
Any way to fix this?

- 1st screenshot: Closed keyboard, with
  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
- 2nd screenshot: Opened keyboard, with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
- 3rd screenshot: Opened keyboard, without `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

**Code:**

```
<!-- activity.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout ../>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation"
        app:app="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<!-- nav_header_navigation.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_navigation_avatar"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_big"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_white_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <LinearLayout .../>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: Have you applied `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity?

Comment: Same result. `adjustPan` is kind of a solution, evne though it's not perfect, because the menu is not visible at all.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm dealing with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

> **android:windowSoftInputMode** 
>   How the main window of the activity
>   interacts with the window containing the on-screen soft keyboard. The
>   setting for this attribute affects two things: The state of the soft
>   keyboard — whether it is hidden or visible — when the activity becomes
>   the focus of user attention. The adjustment made to the activity's
>   main window — whether it is resized smaller to make room for the soft
>   keyboard or whether its contents pan to make the current focus visible
>   when part of the window is covered by the soft keyboard.